# Where am I supposed to install libraries in centos?

Tags: installation, centos

I want to compile and install a library using the standard unixy system of `configure`, `make`, `sudo make install`. On the Ubuntu based systems I am used to, I can put libraries in `/usr/local/lib` and they will be found at run time. This is usually the default install location for most build systems.

I am now using a CentOS system for the first time and I find that `/usr/local/lib` does not appear to be a standard location, my libraries cannot be loaded at run time as they cannot be found. So, my question, what, if any, are the standard install locations where I can put my libraries on CentOS such that they can be found, without messing around with LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to update `/etc/ld.so.conf` to include `/usr/local/lib` (and then run `ldconfig` to regenerate the linker cache). You can also use the `-rpath` linker argument to embed the lib path into the resultant executable. This can be safer when tinkering with a running system.

Comment: ok, but just to be clear, there's no standard place equivalent to `/usr/local/lib` on centos where people are supposed to put built libs by default and that's already on the path?

Comment: I don't have a CentOS box handy but I'm pretty sure there are no defaults so it's just that Linux defaults, which don't include `/usr/local`. Also I forgot to mention it, make sure you run `ldconfig` after changing the file.

Comment: You can also always use `ldconfig -v` to see what paths the linker knows about.

Comment: I found this: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=144967 so I guess red hat decided it was too confusing for users.